# How to know correct carrier

Tags: carrier

I use NumVerify API in order to get the carrier of my mobile phone.
The result of this API is Telefonica Moviles Argentina SA.

But my number is ported out, i think the original is COMPANIA DE RADIOCOMUNICACIONES.

Do you know any application that helps me to get the original carrier when my number is ported out?

I need this because we use another API to send sms according to the carrier.

Comment: If you are sending SMS, wouldn't it be a matter of who is actually servicing the phone at that time?  In which case, if your service is through the company you first mention, then it would be correct.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  But the cost of every service is different according to the carrier. So I get the carrier and the result is A. Then I send the sms using the API we have for carrier A, but this service tells me the carrier of that number is B. (What happens is that the first carrier was B and then it changed of carrier using port number)